# trimming characters up to colon

Tags: iphone

i have a json replay string and the data in that is some what like this

```
NSString *s = responseDrugInfo.genericname;
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":"];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s); 

"genName":"METFORMIN",
   "mtr":" TEVA",
   "comUse":" This medicine is a biguanide-type medicine used along with a diet and exercise     program to control high blood sugar in patients with type 2 diabetes."
```

and i just want to display the data in a lable like this

METFORMIN
TEVA
This medicine is a biguanide-type medicine used along with a diet and exercise program to control high blood sugar in patients with type 2 diabetes.

and using the following code i am able to replace the colon symblo ...

can any one please tell me how to trim the string up to the colon ie how to remove "genName":
 in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the help of following code:

```
NSString *list = @"Norman : Stanley : Fletcher";
NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@" : "];
```

And then divide your array in two parts take even numbers as your value.